# Files gets Forbidden(Status 403) after deployed to iis with Blazor Server

Tags: iis, deployment, blazor, blazor-server-side

After I deployed my project I got status 403 on some javascript bootstrap & css files(not all). I don't understand why I get this error because it seems to work fine locally, when I run with visual studio. My application is Blazor Server and runs on .Net 6. I have checked in the application pool and the .Net CLR version is set to V4.0. And that the javascript, bootstrap & css files exists where they are hosted from. I've also checked and there are some specific permissions with the files, which it doesn't seem like either.

Comment: How about not using https? You could use process monitor to observer access denied events.

Comment: You can start from IIS log files to learn the substatus codes. Then failed request tracing can show you more about the details, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85